# Facing problem in transferring data in request body in login/signup form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, backend

I have made login/signup page and the corresponding routes using NodeJS. The problem i am facing is that on clicking submit button, signup route is calling but the data is not transferring in request body.
this error message is showing

> {"message":"User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., password: Path `password` is required."},
> I have also run this route on postman. there everything is functioning properly. data is properly store in database.

This is the signup form.

```
<div id="signup-form">
        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <form method="post" action="/signup">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" for="username">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" for="password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Signup</button>
        </form>
        <div class="instead-button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Login instead</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is backend code

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('inside');
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.create({ username, password });
    res.status(201);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's small mistake you have done in your HTML code.
When you do the form submission, the body will be taken by the `name` attributes of input fields.
But
You have added `for` attribute to `input` field. And `name` attribute is missing.

Hence the issue is.

Change your code to this :

```
<div id="signup-form">
        <h2>Signup</h2>
        <form method="post" action="/signup">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Signup</button>
        </form>
        <div class="instead-button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Login instead</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot define name attribute in html form input element

```
 <div id="signup-form">
    <h2>Signup</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/signup">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" for="username">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input  name="password" type="password" class="form-control" for="password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Signup</button>
    </form>
    <div class="instead-button">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showLoginForm()">Login instead</button>
    </div>
</div>
```